# Occasional OSX kernel panic in RetrieveINQUIRYData()

Tags: macos, driver, kernel-extension, scsi

I have a SCSI driver which calls `IOSCSIPrimaryCommandsDevice::RetrieveINQUIRYData()` as part of the startup process. Sometimes, after unplugging, ejecting, re-inserting and generally abusing the device during testing, a kernel panic occurs in there.

The [signature](http://forge.voodooprojects.org/svn/chameleon/trunk/i386/include/IOKit/scsi/IOSCSIPrimaryCommandsDevice.h) of this function is:

```
bool RetrieveINQUIRYData (
    UInt8 EVPD,
    UInt8 inquiryPage,
    UInt8 * inquiryBuffer,
    UInt16 * dataSize);
```

The routine which calls this starts like this. It is modelled after PublishUnitSerialNumber from [IOSCSITargetDevice.cpp](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily/IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily-136.3.4/IOSCSIArchitectureModel/IOSCSITargetDevice.cpp)

```
void MyDriverClass::PublishUnitSerialNumber ( IOService *             object )
{
    bool                            result                                  = false;
    SCSICmd_INQUIRY_Page80_Header * data                                    = NULL;
    IOBufferMemoryDescriptor *      buffer                                  = NULL;
    OSString *                      string                                  = NULL;
    char                            serialNumber[kINQUIRY_MaximumDataSize]  = { 0 };
    UInt16                          length                                  = 0;
    SInt16                          serialLength                            = 0;

    DEBUG_LOG("%s[%p]::%s(%p)\n", getName(), this, __FUNCTION__, object);

    buffer = IOBufferMemoryDescriptor::withCapacity ( kINQUIRY_MaximumDataSize, kIODirectionIn );
    require( buffer != NULL, ErrorExit );

    data = (SCSICmd_INQUIRY_Page80_Header*) buffer->getBytesNoCopy();
    length = kINQUIRY_MaximumDataSize;

    require(data != NULL, ReleaseBuffer);

    bzero ( data, kINQUIRY_MaximumDataSize );

    result = RetrieveINQUIRYData ( 0x01,
                                      kINQUIRY_Page80_PageCode,
                                      ( UInt8 * ) data,
                                      &length ); //PANIC IN HERE!

    require ( result, ReleaseBuffer );
    require ( ( data->PAGE_CODE == kINQUIRY_Page80_PageCode ), ReleaseBuffer );
```

This works most of the time, it's only occasionally that it panics. The GDB backtrace is faily unhelpful, as there are no symbols in that function, so all I know is that it's after another function call. I also can't find the source for this function - I think it's part of the closed-source IOKit code.

```
#0  Debugger (message=0x8001003b <Address 0x8001003b out of bounds>) at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1504.15.3/osfmk/i386/AT386/model_dep.c:867
#1  0xffffff8000204d15 in panic (str=0xffffff800057ecb8 "Kernel trap at 0x%016llx, type %d=%s, registers:\nCR0: 0x%016llx, CR2: 0x%016llx, CR3: 0x%016llx, CR4: 0x%016llx\nRAX: 0x%016llx, RBX: 0x%016llx, RCX: 0x%016llx, RDX: 0x%016llx\nRSP: 0x%016llx, RBP: 0x%0"...) at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1504.15.3/osfmk/kern/debug.c:303
#2  0xffffff80002d1208 in panic_trap [inlined] () at :1100
#3  0xffffff80002d1208 in kernel_trap (state=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>) at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1504.15.3/osfmk/i386/trap.c:1001
#4  0xffffff80002e3f4a in trap_from_kernel () at pmap.h:215
#5  0xffffff7f808040b6 in ?? ()
#6  0xffffff7f80804b8b in ?? ()
#7  0xffffff7f80f1324c in com_company_driver_myDriver::PublishUnitSerialNumber (this=0xffffff80130e0600, object=0xffffff8015375000) at /Volumes/user/src/driver/MyDriver.cpp:106
#8  0xffffff7f80f13553 in com_company_driver_myDriver::start (this=0xffffff80130e0600, provider=0xffffff8015375000) at /Volumes/user/src/driver/MyDriver.cpp:53
#9  0xffffff800052d5a6 in IOService::startCandidate (this=0x2710, service=0xe) at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1504.15.3/iokit/Kernel/IOService.cpp:2879
#10 0xffffff800052dcb1 in IOService::probeCandidates (this=0xffffff8015375000, matches=<value temporarily unavailable, due to optimizations>) at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1504.15.3/iokit/Kernel/IOService.cpp:2798
...
...
```

Is there something I should be checking or doing before calling `RetrieveINQUIRYData()` that I am not doing in the above code? From what I can see, all the pointers are checked for NULL, the lengths are set to constants and the only other argument is the literal for EVPD.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the SCSI stack, but here are a few ideas:

1. Even the closed-source kexts have basic debug symbols. So if you `add-kext` the relevant kext from `/System/Library/Extensions/` you should at least get function/method names (and signatures, if C++). You won't get line numbers of course, but you'll get function disassembly boundaries, etc.
2. The panic message is interesting:

`#0  Debugger (message=0x8001003b <Address 0x8001003b out of bounds>) at /SourceCache/xnu/xnu-1504.15.3/osfmk/i386/AT386/model_dep.c:867`

In the 10.6.8 sources, I can't find where that message is coming from, so I'm not quite sure what bounds are expected and where this requirement is coming from. It looks like it might be a physical address though - can you maybe insert some `kprintf` debug output to dump your buffer's `getPhysicalSegment(0, NULL, 0)` result and see if that matches the address that triggers the KP? If that's not it, see if you can figure out what instruction is causing the crash and where the incorrect address is coming from.

Good luck!